# Find and edit item within a stack?

Tags: vb.net, text, stack, edit

I have a stack that has multiple details in each. How can I retrieve a specific item from that stack by searching for it? 
I would also like to edit and save the items I have retrieved? And also display what items need to be moved in order to remove that item?

For example:
123, 456, 789
Are the items in the stack.

How would I retrieve '456' from searching '4' and be able to edit "5" and "6" then save it. And also display that '123' needs to be moved to retrieve '456'?

Thanks.

Comment: The whole point of a stack is the FILO behaviour.  If you want to retrieve items arbitrarily then why do you have a stack in the first place?  What is the actual object you are using?  Is it a `Stack` or `Stack(Of T)` or is it something else, e.g. a `List(Of T)`, so it's not actually a stack at all?

Comment: You *could* use `.ToArray()`, modify it and rebuild the stack, but as mentioned that defeats the purpose of using a `Stack(Of T)`

Comment: Then what would be the best approach of this forgetting the stack?